# Problems with pagination

Tags: php, pagination, query-string

I am working on a university project, which is based on e-shopping, i tried this code to implement my result, this gives no error but it does not work when I press next page link or "button" please help any help would be appreciated

```
            <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","php184_proj_db");

             // Check connection
             if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
              {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }

            if (!(isset($pagenum)))
            {
            $pagenum = 1;
            }
            //Here we count the number of results
            //Edit $qry to be your query
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM posts";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            //This is the number of results displayed per page
            $page_rows = 5;
            //This tells us the page number of our last page
            $last = ceil($row/$page_rows);
            //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages
            if ($pagenum < 1)
            {
            $pagenum = 1; //Pagination of MySQL Query Results Setting the Variables
            }
            elseif ($pagenum > $last)
            {
            $pagenum = $last;
            }
            //This sets the range to display in our query
            $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 
                             $j=0;
                $qry = "SELECT * FROM posts $max";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                $j++;
                    echo "<p>";
            // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number Query and Results of pages
            echo " --Page $pagenum of $last--
            <p>";
            // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a 
            //link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't
            //then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

            if ($pagenum == 1)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'>
            <<-First</a>
            ";
            echo " ";
            $previous = $pagenum-1;
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?
            pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a>
            ";
            }
            //just a spacer
            echo " ---- ";
            //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page,
            //and then generating the Next and Last links
            if ($pagenum == $last)
            {
            }
            else {
            $next = $pagenum+1;
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next
            -></a> ";
            echo " ";
            echo " <a
            href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last
            ->></a> ";

            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Although your question merits some attention, I would suggest that you take a look at this [checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and see if you can provide some more insights/details into the problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit this URL: `http://example.com/somepage.php?key=val`, you don't automatically get a variable `$key` inside PHP. Instead, you have to use [`$_GET['key']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), which will hold the value. (in this case: 'val')

So, somewhere in the beginning of your code, add the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['pagenum']) && $_GET['pagenum'] >= 1) {
    $pagenum = (int) $_GET['pagenum'];
} else {
    $pagenum = 1;
}
```

Not only does this create the `$pagenum` variable and give it the value from the URL, it also makes sure that the value is a valid number. If not, or if the URL doesn't contain a `pagenum`, it is set to `1`.

Possible scenario's:

- `pagenum` contains not an integer, but a string (might even be a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attempt)
- `pagenum` is a negative number, or 0
- `pagenum` isn't set at all

In all of the above cases, `pagenum` is set to `1`.

If `pagenum` contains a float (for instance `1.5.`), the value will be cast to an integer. In the case of 1.5, `pagenum` will become 1.

Remember, always make sure you sanitize user input.

Comment: thx dude but its not working at any instance, I can see the ?page=2 at address bar, but its appending next posts????

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. However if you're using `?page=2` in the links, you have to refer to `$_GET['page']` instead of `$_GET['pagenum']`. You must use the same key in `$_GET[]` as in the URL.